# How can I take my successful prototype from jsfiddle and make it available on my website

Tags: jquery

Im teaching myself to code and I am lost. Im trying to take the jsfiddle prototype and add it into my website.  I used Sandvox to build the site...again I cant code.

I made [this](http://jsfiddle.net/6qsqedhf/1/) (modified code) and now Id like to have the results run on my website.  Any help would be much appreciated.

```
HTML
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>

<div id="container" style="min-width: 500px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto"></div>

JS
$(function () {
$('#container').highcharts({
    chart: {
        type: 'column'
    },
    title: {
        text: 'Prevalence of Peformance Enhancing Drug Use By Sport'
    },
    subtitle: {
        text: 'Source: <a href="http://www.samuelwbennett.com">getfast</a>'
    },
    xAxis: {
        type: 'category',
        labels: {
            rotation: -45,
            style: {
                fontSize: '13px',
                fontFamily: 'Verdana, sans-serif'
            }
        }
    },
    yAxis: {
        min: 0,
        title: {
            text: 'Prevalence (%)'
        }
    },
    legend: {
        enabled: false
    },
    tooltip: {
        pointFormat: 'Population in 2008: <b>{point.y:.1f} millions</b>'
    },
    series: [{
        name: 'Prevalence',
        data: [
            ['WADA All Pros', 2],
            ['Child Athletes', 4],
            ['HS Football', 6.3],
            ['HS Seniors All Sports', 6.6],
            ['Amatuer Weight-lifters', 8.2],
            ['American Football', 9],
            ['Baseball', 9.4],
            ['Research Estimate All Pros', 10.2],
            ['Top 100 Sprinters (running)', 40],
            ['Professional Bodybuilders', 54],
            ['Tour de France Winners', 79],

        ],
        dataLabels: {
            enabled: true,
            rotation: -90,
            color: '#FFFFFF',
            align: 'right',
            x: 4,
            y: 10,
            style: {
                fontSize: '13px',
                fontFamily: 'Verdana, sans-serif',
                textShadow: '0 0 3px black'
            }
        }
    }]
});
```

});

Answer (score 0):

I don't know anything about Sandvox, but as long as you have some way to add custom HTML to your site, just copy and paste all the HTML from your JSFiddle, and then wrap the Javascript in a `<script> paste here </script>` tag, and paste that below the HTML.

You'll also need to make sure you have jQuery included somewhere on the site *before any other scripts that require it*, if its not in there already:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.3.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: *"make sure you have jQuery included somewhere on the site"* - Somewhere *before* any other script elements that use it...

Answer (score 0):

You can use SandVox built-in code injection feature. First, make sure you add `<script>` for that list of library packages on the left column of JSfiddle (ex. jQuery Mobile 1.2.0)

To add the Raw HTML

> click tool bar item "Object" and select "Raw HTML".
>   When you are done, click "Update preview"

Here is a reference: http://www.karelia.com/support/sandvox/help/z/Raw_HTML.html

For JavaScript or more complicate HTML

> go to the Webpage where the HighChart diagram will be displayed and click edit and select "Site Code Injection". Now it is the time to add the libraries you had on the JSFiddle as `<script>`. Use CDN link to load those libraries.

For example, using CDN for adding jQuery Mobile 1.2.0 (minified):

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.js" />
```

Here is the reference: 
http://www.karelia.com/support/sandvox/help/z/Code_Injection.html

UPDATED:

The final page code should look similar to this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
  <title> - jsFiddle demo</title>

  <script type='text/javascript' src='//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js'></script>




  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/result-light.css">

  <style type='text/css'>

  </style>



<script type='text/javascript'>//<![CDATA[ 

$(function () {
    $('#container').highcharts({
        chart: {
            type: 'column'
        },
        title: {
            text: 'Prevalence of Peformance Enhancing Drug Use By Sport'
        },
        subtitle: {
            text: 'Source: <a href="http://www.samuelwbennett.com">getfast</a>'
        },
        xAxis: {
            type: 'category',
            labels: {
                rotation: -45,
                style: {
                    fontSize: '13px',
                    fontFamily: 'Verdana, sans-serif'
                }
            }
        },
        yAxis: {
            min: 0,
            title: {
                text: 'Prevalence (%)'
            }
        },
        legend: {
            enabled: false
        },
        tooltip: {
            pointFormat: 'PED Prevalence: <b>{point.y:.1f} %</b>'
        },
        series: [{
            name: 'Prevalence',
            data: [
                ['WADA All Pros', 2],
                ['Child Athletes', 4],
                ['HS Football', 6.3],
                ['HS Seniors All Sports', 6.6],
                ['Amatuer Weight-lifters', 8.2],
                ['American Football', 9],
                ['Baseball', 9.4],
                ['Research Estimate All Pros', 10.2],
                ['Top 100 Sprinters (running)', 40],
                ['Professional Bodybuilders', 54],
                ['Tour de France Winners', 79],

            ],
            dataLabels: {
                enabled: true,
                rotation: -90,
                color: '#FFFFFF',
                align: 'right',
                x: 4,
                y: -15,
                style: {
                    fontSize: '13px',
                    fontFamily: 'Verdana, sans-serif',
                    textShadow: '0 0 3px black'
                }
            }
        }]
    });
});
//]]>  

</script>


</head>
<body>
  <script src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>

<div id="container" style="min-width: 500px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto"></div>


</body>


</html>
```

Comment: Thank you.  Still doesnt work.  I added the following HTML via 'Object' and then raw HTML:                                                                                             <script src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>

<div id="container" style="min-width: 500px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto"></div>                                                                                                        Next I added the JS from my fiddle using 'Page Code Injection" to the "Document Body".

Comment: @SamuelBennett I added the entire code here so you have a reference. Try right click the mouse on the page and view page source to see if it contains the code above. It may have more than this since it has a template already. Make sure you added it in correct section of HTML <head> and <body>. Good luck

Answer (score 0):

In the HTML section at the bottom of right side, right-click it to bring context menu, View Frame Source, and then the source page will pop-up. Here is the screenshot for how to get it.[image]